# WebDriver Crashes Chrome Randomly

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

While running my test suit in Google Chrome using Selenium ChromeDriver it often crashes the browser with the message "Whoa! Chrome has crashed. Relaunch now?". Basically causes non-deterministic behavior in the code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

// Set chromeDriver path
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// Force english
options.addArguments("--lang=en");

// Launch chrome
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
... // Click elements, fill text fields, etc.
```

Here is an example exception that is thrown:

```
[137.372][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=31.0.1650.63)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.22 seconds
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6b', time: '2013-08-12 15:43:19'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\PRENAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir2076_16030}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=31.0.1650.63, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 596eb8b1a989584e999a48b9d94f910d
```

The chrome_debug.log file from the scoped_dir2076_16030 folder reads:

```
[9740:9584:0504/013034:ERROR:policy_loader_win.cc(370)] PReg file doesn't exist: C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol
[7304:8360:0504/013035:ERROR:base_feature_provider.cc(122)] manifestTypes: Allowing web_page contexts requires supplying a value for matches.
[9740:9376:0504/013035:ERROR:policy_loader_win.cc(370)] PReg file doesn't exist: C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol
[9740:9376:0504/013035:ERROR:policy_loader_win.cc(370)] PReg file doesn't exist: C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol
[9740:9584:0504/013044:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013045:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013048:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013050:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013052:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013054:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013056:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013101:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013102:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013104:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013105:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013107:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013108:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013111:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013112:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013117:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013119:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013120:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[9740:9584:0504/013132:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[8712:7424:0504/013139:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(404)] pipe error: 232
[9740:9584:0504/013143:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[5276:9684:0504/013152:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
[9740:9584:0504/013153:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[8268:10092:0504/013158:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
[2528:616:0504/013203:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
[9740:9584:0504/013205:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[7112:5484:0504/013215:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
[9740:9584:0504/013215:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[5400:8440:0504/013220:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
[9740:9584:0504/013227:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
[8656:9276:0504/013231:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
```

Comment: please provide any sort of example, preferably with code. this question is not answerable in this state.

Comment: PReg file doesn't exist: C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol
 If you don't fix this then it follows you get more errors.

Answer (score 0):

one thing that i've discovered is that if you stop the test before completion where you close the chromeDriver, say you're running in debugger mode and terminate the run, the chromeDriver process still exists in your task manager. This can build up and it uses up all of your resources. This problem stopped occurring when I go rid of all of these still existing processes.